# Branch office unable to resolve DNS names

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Environment - MS Server 2003 AD Domain, XP computers at Branch office connected by VPN back to main office. T

IP Traffic to the internet and internally is relatively stable, but the in-house application has been buggy, and dropping connections. Users report "slowness"

DNS Name resolution might be the culprit or a symptom, I cannot ping workstations at the main office by name, but can ping their IP Address...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have DCs at the branch? Can you make a quick Visio of your topology? There's not enough info here to help us solve your problem other than saying "yeah, sounds like DNS"

Answer (score 2):

Point your branch office servers to a DNS server that had a copy of your internal DNS zones. If you have DNS servers there, point them at that. If you don't, point them at the main office DNS servers (but understand what that means in the event of a failure).

Comment: Sorry I really dropped the ball on this, but wanted to say thanks for the reply.